# Signing Jar files

Tags: java, jar, applet, sign

I have purchased a code signing certificate for signing my jar files. After adding the whole chain of trust to the keystore, signing and validating the jar file I get this output:

```
sm       905 Tue Jul 22 15:48:42 CEST 2014 com/siemens/util/OSLogin$1.class
sm       881 Tue Jul 22 15:48:42 CEST 2014 com/siemens/util/OSLogin$2.class
sm      1802 Tue Jul 22 15:48:42 CEST 2014 com/siemens/util/OSLogin.class
s        434 Tue Jul 22 15:48:42 CEST 2014 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
         444 Tue Jul 22 15:48:42 CEST 2014 META-INF/_B8D178A3-25F1-4475-8D11-C37
A786279F4_.SF
        6413 Tue Jul 22 15:48:42 CEST 2014 META-INF/_B8D178A3-25F1-4475-8D11-C37
A786279F4_.RSA

  s = signature was verified
  m = entry is listed in manifest
  k = at least one certificate was found in keystore
  i = at least one certificate was found in identity scope

jar verified.

Warning:
This jar contains signatures that does not include a timestamp. Without a timest
amp, users may not be able to validate this jar after the signer certificate's e
xpiration date (2017-07-21) or after any future revocation date.
```

But after copying the jar to the web server and opening the webpage on the same system I get "The certificate is not valid..."
Did I miss something? I'm new to code signing.

Regards
mannson

Comment: What versions of Java are you running on each?

Comment: Build 1.7.0_60-b19) on both systems. It's not the latest version, but I'm not allowed to update the server.

Comment: Did u find solution? What company certificate did u buy ?

Comment: It works now. The jar signing was OK, but the SSL certificate of my web server had been expired :)